# C getchar loop to get integer input from user - [how to improve]

Tags: c, loops, input, getchar

Is there more elegant way to do this task?

Program asks user for integer and repeats if non-digital characters are entered.
To exit loop two conditions expected:
a) all entered characters are digits
b) last character is '\n'

Short solutions like scanf don’t work properly, other approaches require lots of variables loops and if else conditions. User input is common task and I would like to have proper reusable template.

Subjective opinions are appreciated. Way to simplify this function or advice on another solution. Improve formatting. Reading for more systematic understanding.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getIntOnly();

int main() {
    int x = 0;
    x = getIntOnly();
    printf("\nvalue entered is: %d \n", x);
}

int getIntOnly() {
    int ch, num, quit, abc;

    do {
        num = 0;
        ch = 0;
        quit = 0;
        abc = 0;
        printf("Enter the input: ");

        do {
            ch = getchar();
            if (ch >= 48 && ch <= 57) {
                num = num * 10 + (ch - 48);
            }
            else if (ch == '\n') {
                quit = 1;
            }
            else {
                abc = 1;
            }

        }
        while (quit == 0);

    }
    while (quit == 0 || abc == 1);
    return (num);
}
```

Comment: Read a line with `fgets()`. You can then use `strtol()` to parse it as a number.

Comment: For more complex input: for command-line processing, usually it's better to specify arguments instead of interaction, (GNU [getopt](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html)). For the situations which user input is common, usually you would also go and also use a terminal API ([ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)). If you want to parse input, consider using `lex` _et al_ ([re2c](https://re2c.org/)) and maybe `yacc`/`bison`/`lemon`.

Comment: Don't hard code `48` and `57`, use `'0'` and `'9'`.  But don't do that either; use `isdigit`

Comment: YukaMax, Do you want to prevent overflow?  What about a leading sign + or -?

Comment: chux - Reinstate Monica, the task is only to get positive numbers, but it is interesting to build same program also for + and -. Preventing overflow is better.

Answer (score 2):

Using `fgets()` means you'll get the full text at once.
You can then examine it (and convert it too) to suit your needs.

```
int getIntOnly( void ) {
    int value = 0, i = 0;
    char buf[ 64 ];

    do {
        printf( "Enter integer value: " );

        
        fgets( buf, sizeof( buf ), stdin );
        
        value = 0;
        for( i = 0; '0' <= buf[i] && buf[i] <= '9'; i++ )
            value = value * 10 + buf[i] - '0';

    } while( buf[i] != '\n' ); // good! reached end of line

    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be better? Add some validity checks for the result of `fgets()` and `strtol()` according to your original code.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int getIntOnly();

int main() {
    int x = 0;
    x = getIntOnly();
    printf("\nvalue entered is: %d \n", x);
}

bool isDigit(char ch) {
    return (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')? true : false;
}

bool isAllDigit(char *buf) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; buf[i] != '\n'; i++) {
        if (isDigit(buf[i]) == false) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool isVaildInt(long int number) {
    return (number >= INT_MIN && number <= INT_MAX)? true : false;
}

int getIntOnly() {
    char buf[100];
    long int num;
    bool done = false;

    do {
        /* read line-by-line */
        fgets(buf, 100, stdin);
        if (isAllDigit(buf) == false)
            continue;

        num = strtol(buf, NULL, 10);
        /* strtol() returns long int */
        if (isVaildInt(num) == false)
            continue;
        done = true;
    } while (done == false);
    return num;
}
```